# How to generate anchor IDs for definition (labeled) lists in AsciiDoc or reStructuredText?

Tags: github, restructuredtext, asciidoc

I'm writing documentation on GitHub, and would like to make hashtag links to individual terms in my definition lists (AKA labeled lists, description lists). Example:  `https://github.com/username/projectname/wiki/SomeArticle#my-term`

Kramdown provides a neat [feature](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/converter/html.html#definition-lists) that generates element IDs for all terms in a definition list. However, Kramdown cannot be used as the renderer in GitHub wikis.

Is there a similar feature for AsciiDoc or reStructuredText? For what I know:

- AsciiDoc allows [defining custom anchors](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#anchordef). But I don't want to manually add anchors if possible.
- (sphinx-powered) reStructuredText supports [creating and linking to custom labels](https://thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/sphinx/rest_syntax.html#explicit-links), but it doesn't seem to work on GitHub.
- reStructuredText allows you to link to any term in a [glossary](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#glossary-directive) using the [`:term:`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-term) role. However, GitHub does not support the `.. glossary::` directive, either.

Short of moving away from GitHub wiki (which is a poor option for me), what can I do?

Comment: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#ref-role

Answer (score 1):

For Asciidoctor, you can add an identifier to each term in a definition list:

```
[[apple]]Apple::
  A red fruit

[[banana]]Banana::
  A yellow fruit
```

Then you can link to them with the in-page cross reference syntax:

```
See <<apple>> for more details.
```

As you can see, the markup is fairly simple. If you don't want to manually add the identifier, you could write a script to add them. For example, if you have a document like:

```
= Document

Apple::
  A red fruit.

Banana::
  A yellow fruit.
```

You can do this:

```sh
cat file.adoc | perl -ne 's/^([^:\[]+)::$/[[\L$1\E]]$1::/; print $_'
```

which prints:

```
= Document

[[apple]]Apple::
  A red fruit.

[[banana]]Banana::
  A yellow fruit.
```

If you need to save the result, do this:

```sh
cat file.adoc | perl -ne 's/^([^:\[]+)::$/[[\L$1\E]]$1::/; print $_' > file_with_id.adoc
```

Note: If your definition list contains terms with spaces, you would need to do more work to convert the spaces to hyphens, or other HTML-safe identifier characters.